# Should I uninstall the Intel graphics kernel mode driver?

Tags: windows-vista, sleep, intel-graphics

My installation of Windows Vista says that the Intel graphics kernel mode driver is causing Windows to resume slowly and offers an option to remove it from the list.

I presume this would increase my speed. Should I do it? If necessary, can I restore the driver?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the dialog/message?

Comment: Only get as much as storage as you need. And if you can i would get a SSD.

Comment: Welcome to superuser. Your original question would be fine here, but we don't normally ask more than one question a question around here. You might want to roll back to the last edit. Your 'new' question on the other hand, is seriously subjective - while you won't be able to use the full 4gb of ram on a 32 bit OS, that has nothing to do with your hard drive. If you get a bit more rep, you could drop by root access, our chat room, and our preferred place for hardware purchase related discussions.